# How to test system commands in go

Tags: go

Given I have a function like:

```
func getTotalMemory() string {
  out,_ := exec.Command("grep", "MemTotal", "/proc/meminfo").Output()
  t := strings.Split(string(out), ":")
  x := strings.TrimSpace(t[1])
  return x
}
```

How can I write a test for that function to make sure I'm parsing it properly? In ruby I would just do something like

```
os.expects(:Command).and_returns("string")
```

I'm currently using GoConvey if that has any impact on answers.

Thanks!

Comment: On a side note, why can't you just read that file using Go itself, scan its lines looking for the one starting with `MemTotal` and then parse out the rest? Calling out to `grep` for getting such information is overkill. See also [`github.com/jandre/procfs`](http://godoc.org/github.com/jandre/procfs)

Comment: @kostix this was just an example I had in some code I had written - you're correct that I should just use go but there are other commands/functions and I thought this was the simplest one to show.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could start by looking at the test policy for [`os.exec` package](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/):
see "[`src/pkg/os/exec/exec_test.go`](http://golang.org/src/pkg/os/exec/exec_test.go)".

Note: [GoConvey](http://goconvey.co/) is compatible with standard Go testing framework, so that won't have any bearing on the kind of test you want to do.

Comment: I don't see anything in the os.exec test package that explains how I can 'mock' the output of these functions so I can test my output parsing unless I'm not understanding something.

Comment: @Josh Lin 25: `helperCommand`: that will run (on `go test`) the function `TestHelperProcess()` which mocks the commands.